# Java parse all values from Array in JSON to ArrayList

Tags: java, json

I have a problem. I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "Market":"USDT",
   "Coin":"BTC",
   "Period":"1h",
   "EmergencyPerc":-25,
   "TakeProfitPerc":1.2,
   "ProtectiveOrdersEnabled":"no",
   "EMACrossMarginPerc":0.5,
   "EMABuySellPeriod":"15m",
   "EMABuySellNameLow":"EMA10",
   "EMABuySellNameHigh":"EMA50",
   "EMAUnfreezePeriod":"1h",
   "EMAUnfreezeNameLow":"EMA20",
   "EMAUnfreezeNameHigh":"EMA200",
   "SimTemplate":"t001",
   "Patterns":{
      "Buy":[
         "buy_pattern_1",
         "buy_pattern_2"
      ],
      "Sell":[
         "sell_pattern_1",
         "sell_pattern_2"
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to parse that JSON to the following class:

```
public class AgentStrategy {
    
    private String Market;
    private String Coin;
    private double EmergencyPerc;
    private double TakeProfitPerc;
    private String ProtectiveOrdersEnabled;
    public double EMACrossMarginPerc;
    public String EMABuySellPeriod;
    public String EMABuySellNameLow;
    public String EMABuySellNameHigh;
    public String EMAUnfreezePeriod;
    public String EMAUnfreezeNameLow;
    public String EMAUnfreezeNameHigh;
    private String SimTemplate;
    private ArrayList<PriceDropSell> PriceDropSells;
    private ArrayList<String> buyPatternsUsed = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> sellPatternsUsed = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

For that I have the following method inside that class:

```
public AgentStrategy parseJsonToObject(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    AgentStrategy agent = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AgentStrategy.class);
    
    // PATTERNS
    Map patternsMap = (Map) map.get("Patterns");
    Map sellMap = (Map) patternsMap.get("Sell");
    Map buyMap = (Map) patternsMap.get("Buy");
    agent.buyPatternsUsed = new ArrayList<>(sellMap.values());
    agent.buyPatternsUsed = new ArrayList<>(buyMap.values());
    
    return agent;
}
```

But I get an error on this line at the pattern parse part:

```
agent.buyPatternsUsed = new ArrayList<>(sellMap.values());
```

With: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

How can I parse all the patterns from buy and sell to a String Array (seperate)?

Comment: You can use `@SerializedName` to manage the difference in Java fields and json fields. This will help with java variables naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I parse all the patterns from buy and sell to a String Array (seperate)?

The JSON you posted has two arrays and you're trying to parse them as maps. Parse them as arrays (lists).

```
List sellList = (List) patternsMap.get("Sell");
List buyList = (List) patternsMap.get("Buy");
```

That said, the true power of GSON (and JSON parsers in general) is that do the heavy work for you if you model your classes correctly. You could have a "Patterns" class that has two lists of strings, then the strategy class would have a "Pattern". For example:

```
class Patterns {
    List<String> Buy;
    List<String> Sell;
}

class Agent Strategy {
    Patterns Patterns;
}
```

Now, when you parse the object, because the class structure matches the json structure, the lists are parsed automatically for you:

```
AgentStrategy agent = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AgentStrategy.class);
// agent.Patterns.Buy and .Sell now have the lists
```

Then you could just define helpers to get the data you care about:

```
class Agent Strategy {
    Patterns Patterns;

    public getBuyPatternsUsed() { return Patterns.Buy; }
    public getSellPatternsUsed() { return Patterns.Sell; }
}
```

P.S. - Tip: when you see "class cast exception" use your debugger to step through up to line where the crash happens and see what type you're *actually* getting compared to what you *expect*. That will help you debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
      "Buy":[
         "buy_pattern_1",
         "buy_pattern_2"
      ],
      "Sell":[
         "sell_pattern_1",
         "sell_pattern_2"
      ]
```

The `Buy` and `Sell` are arrays.

So the following cast will throw exception

```
    Map sellMap = (Map) patternsMap.get("Sell");
    Map buyMap = (Map) patternsMap.get("Buy");
```

### Suggestion

1. Try to use annotations to map the java attribute name and json field name
2. i have only named few fields (using `@SerializedName` annotation)

```java
    static class PriceDropSell {

        @SerializedName("Buy")
        List<String> buy;

        @SerializedName("Sell")
        List<String> sell;
    }

    static class AgentStrategy {

        private String Market;
        private String Coin;
        private double EmergencyPerc;
        private double TakeProfitPerc;
        private String ProtectiveOrdersEnabled;
        public double EMACrossMarginPerc;
        public String EMABuySellPeriod;
        public String EMABuySellNameLow;
        public String EMABuySellNameHigh;
        public String EMAUnfreezePeriod;
        public String EMAUnfreezeNameLow;
        public String EMAUnfreezeNameHigh;
        private String SimTemplate;

        @SerializedName(("Patterns"))
        private PriceDropSell Patterns;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        AgentStrategy agentStrategy = gson.fromJson(str, AgentStrategy.class);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(agentStrategy));
    }
```